# Angularjs Highlight is displaying last row (i.e; $index) after sorting the name

Tags: angularjs, sorting, indexing

I am sorry for posting questions regularly about Angularjs, I am new to this and lot of confustion is there this is the reason I am posting the questions.

My doubt is I have a list of names whenever I created a new list the highlight is displaying the created name which is working but when I tried to set that names in alphabetical order the highlight issue is displaying the new $index value which is adding. I tried to pass the id in place of $index which is not and highlight is also not displaying. Here is the code which i tried

```
<table data-ng-repeat="SupplierModels in Supplierlist | filter:suppliersearch">
    <tr>
        <td class="roundedCorners6_account" ng-class='{roundedCorners6_account_active: $index==selectedRowslist}' style="width: 200px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center;">
            <div ng-click="showSupplier(SupplierModels.supplier_ID, $index)">{{SupplierModels.supplier_Name | truncate}}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

$scope function is

```
function initialLoading() {
    ServiceFactory.Invoke(baseurl + 'Api/SupplierApi/SupplierList').success(function (success) {
        $scope.Supplierlist = success;
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error);
    })
}

$scope.SaveSupplier = function () {
    $scope.IsValidatesupplierData($scope);
    if ($rootScope.alerts.length == 0) {
        ServiceFactory.InvokeWithParameters(baseurl + 'Api/SupplierApi/SaveSupplier', $scope.supplier).success(function (success) {
            initialLoading();
            var rows = $scope.selectedRowslist == undefined ? $scope.Supplierlist.length : $scope.selectedRowslist;
            var supId = success;
            $scope.showSupplier(supId, rows);
            $scope.visible = true;
        }).error(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        })
    }
    else {
        $rootScope.isErrorPopUpShow = true;
    }
}

$scope.showSupplier = function (id, rows) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    ServiceFactory.InvokeWithParameters(baseurl + 'Api/SupplierApi/SupplierDetail?supplierId=' + id).success(function (success) {
        $scope.supplier = success;
        $scope.selectedRowslist = rows;
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error);
    })
}
```

[image: Example View]

I hope I gave a proper explanation. Thanks

Comment: What are you tring to do with `rows` and $index ?

Comment: highlighting the list item

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a natural id in the data model.
  `id` would work, but does `supplier` have an id field?  If so you could use that.

```
<td class="roundedCorners6_account" 
    ng-class='{roundedCorners6_account_active: activeSupplierID== SupplierModels.supplier_ID}'
```

---

```
$scope.showSupplier = function (id, rows) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    ServiceFactory.InvokeWithParameters(baseurl + 'Api/SupplierApi/SupplierDetail?supplierId=' + id).success(function (success) {
        $scope.supplier = success;
        $scope.activeSupplierID = id;  //supplier.id ? if it exists.
  ...
};
```

Comment: I can't help you if you just say `it doesn't work`.  You can't use $index, you need to use something specific to the data that is being selected.  In this case it looks like `SupplierModels. supplier_ID` is your key.  You save that on scope, and use that in ng-class

Comment: I used SupplierModels. supplier_ID in place of $index, functionality is working but highlight is missing. I tried to pass id in scope function also but no use, actually i tried all possible methods.

Comment: @Cathy can you either provide me a fiddle.. or update below your post the html you are trying ?